# how can I pass value from java variable as callback to Unity c# Variable or function (through Android plugin)

Tags: java, c#, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I am writing a Plugin for Unity3D in Android Studio (Java) and I want to pass a boolean value as callback to Unity C# variable or function. I need help in this.

Comment: I think you want to have an event in Unity that is called from Java and Java Passes a parameter to the event.  See following : http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/event.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Java-side:

```
public static void SendUnityResults()
{
    boolean yourBool = false;
    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("gameObjectNameThatReceiveTheValue", "CallbackMethodName", String.valueOf(yourBool));
}
```

On your Unity-side:

Make a GameObject with the name "`gameObjectNameThatReceiveTheValue`" and with a public method called "`CallbackMethodName`".

Edit: Added Unity-side method

```
public void CallbackMethodName(string yourStringedBool)
{
    bool yourBool = bool.Parse(yourStringedBool);
    Debug.Log("Your bool received with value:" + yourBool);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply.Can you please post unity side method also?

Comment: Thankyou I am getting error while passing yourBool it says only strings are allowed here   
 UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("gameObjectNameThatReceiveTheValue", "CallbackMethodName", yourBool);

Comment: And where should i use GameObject?

Comment: @HamzaAbbas sorry Hamza, completly forgot about the "only string" restriction, I've updated the answer (only make parses from string to bool and so on). You should youse this GameObject on your current active scene. Tell me if it works ^^